# Set the render size using data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I'm using the next code for the my AppBatButton in XAML:

```
 <AppBarButton Icon="Play" Label="Play" Click="btn_Click">
    <AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="{Binding Path=ButtonsRenderSize}" ScaleY="{Binding Path=ButtonsRenderSize}"/>
     </AppBarButton.RenderTransform>
  </AppBarButton>
```

where ButtonsRenderSize is a variable declared on the C# part of the page :

```
    public static double ButtonsRenderSize { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        ButtonsRenderSize = 0.75;
   }
```

The problem is that the binding isn't working. The RenderSize remains 1. Without the binding it works, but I need to modify the RenderSize from code when the windows in not in full-screen mode and I have multiple buttons, so the binding sound the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your binding works, following steps are required:

1. Set DataContext of MainPage to it self so you can bind control's properties to properties in code behind.
2. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise PropertyChanged event every time you give a property new value. With that changing a property value on the fly will give effect to the control's property bound to it.

Example:

```
public partial class MainPage :  PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        ButtonsRenderSize = 0.75;
    }

    private double _buttonsRenderSize;
    public double ButtonsRenderSize 
    {
        get { return _buttonsRenderSize; }
        set 
        {  
            if(value != _buttonsRenderSize)
            {
                _buttonsRenderSize = value;
                //raise propertychanged event to notify UI's property to update it's value
                OnPropertyChanged("ButtonsRenderSize");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Great, evything seems to work as long as I use internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) . virtual generates a error and protected a warning, but no problem if I use internal apparently. Thank you very much for the answer! :) One question though: can I move the OnPropertyChanged and all the lines between #region and #endregion in another class (just for better code managment) ? If yes, I will need to implement :INotifyPropertyChanged on that class only, right ?

Comment: Yes you can create a base class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged then make classes to bind inherit base class so you don't have to reimplement INotifyPropertyChanged every where. But common practice is those classes to bind are not the code behind, it usually viewmodels. And by creating viewmodels you are closer to implement [Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). That's widely used pattern around WP & WPF and i recommend to look into it.